# Hide specific wire line

Tags: edges, freestyle, wireframe

In this model using 2.70 with toon-rendering and freestyle some edges (circled in red in the image) are rendered that should not be rendered.

[image: image, unliked lines marked]

I am a old man came from very old blender, so please be specific!

How can i keep only these edges from rendering?

Comment: Are you using freestyle to render the edges? For freestyle you can mark specific edges to be rendered as lines.

Comment: Every object has edges, so yes i render edges (what does you mean?)! Yes, i have the feature "freestyle" activated. What do i have to do? Mark the vertices to select a line and press what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got it now.
[image: from left to right]

Every face have a direction, some faces had a wrong side, so i had to flip the faces.